# Loop throug the data frame applying some function on each value in R

Tags: r

I am new to R . I have a data frame(usr.query) with structure as shown below

[[image: This is my data frame[1]]

Now I want to take text of each id and compare it to text of all the other id and and if there is a match, i want to append it to a new column say count of match.

```
A0008 with A0043,A0065,A0082,B0018,B0026
A0043 with A0008,A0065,A0082,B0018,B0026
```

Function to apply

```
count_match = length(intersect(unlist(strsplit(query1," ")),unlist(strsplit(query2," "))))
```

The query 1 here is text of A0008 and query 2 is text of A0043,A0065,A0082,B0018,B0026

I tried the suggested solution and here is the result.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No loops are necessary; you'll usually find that's the case in R, because it's really good at utilizing vectorized operations. In this case, you can get the necessary combinations with `combn`, and then make the `match_count` column by subsetting the original data.frame with the combinations of the new one, and testing for equality. Adding zero changes the values from Boolean to numeric (use `as.integer`, if you prefer).

```
# assemble sample data
df <- data.frame(id = 1:5, text = c('apple', 'mango', 'apple', 'apple', 'mango'))

# make combinations
df2 <- as.data.frame(t(combn(df$id, 2)))
# add names
names(df2) <- c('main_id', 'compared_to_id')
# test for match
df2$match_count <- (df[df2$main_id, 'text'] == df[df2$compared_to_id, 'text']) + 0
```

The result:

```
> df2
   main_id compared_to_id match_count
1        1              2           0
2        1              3           1
3        1              4           1
4        1              5           0
5        2              3           0
6        2              4           0
7        2              5           1
8        3              4           1
9        3              5           0
10       4              5           0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot alistare. I just have 2 clarifications in the above said method.

1. what if the id is not integer,suppose its like u001,u002,u003 etc..will combn work?

2. I dont want to use just == operator to compare. My actual funct is as below
text1 <- c("apple mango mango")
text2 <- c("mango apple orange")

length(intersect(unlist(strsplit(text1," ")),unlist(strsplit(text2," "))))

the length value should be match_count..how to incorporate this?

Comment: `combn` should handle strings fine. If it gets temperamental, use `as.character` on any factors (or use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when making your data.fame). Your function is more complicated, but doable. So each entry in `text` in the original data.frame has a string of multiple fruits?, and you're looking for how many unique fruits are in both? Do you want to count repeats? Does position matter? Maybe you need to edit your sample data.

Comment: If I understand what you want properly, you could do keep the same logic with `df4$match_count <- sapply(1:nrow(df4), function(x){length(intersect(unlist(strsplit(df3[df3$id == df4[x,1], 'text']," ")), unlist(strsplit(df3[df3$id == df4[x,2], 'text']," "))))})`.

Comment: Hi alistaire, thanks for sugest but looks like it doesnt still work. I ve added actual data and explaination. See if u can help

Comment: That's a factor issue with `combn`; wrap `df$id` in `as.character` as I said above and it'll go away. That said, you've now completely changed your question from the original; it may be time for a new question. Also, pictures of data are bad; copy and paste or–better–post the results of `dput( yourData )`.